# Migrate AWS account to another country

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had created an AWS account when I was living in India. I ended up never using it so payment information and PAN information (required in AWS India) is not set.

Now that I've moved to the US, I want to use the account for S3. However if I login/sign up with the same account it shows me the account from India. I cannot update the country there. I tried closing my account to start from scratch but when I try to sign up again it takes me to the previous state where the address and country is set to India.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I contacted AWS support and below were the steps that I had to follow to create a new AWS account apart from the AISPL account:

In order to create a new account using the existing AISPL account needs to have an email address related to the account

In order to change the email address associated with your AWS account, you will need to make sure you're signed into the account you'd like to update, then follow the link below:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/account

Click "Edit" next to the "Account Settings" heading. You'll then be taken to a page where you can update the name, email address, and password associated with your AWS account. Please keep in mind, you will not be able to use an email address that is already in use on another Amazon.com or AWS account, and that an email address update will also change the information on the Amazon.com retail account associated with your AWS account as they share the same login information.

Once this email has been changed the previous email will be free to be used in the new account.

To set up a new account

1. Open https://aws.amazon.com/, and then choose to Create an Account.

Note:

This might be unavailable in your browser if you previously signed into the AWS Management Console.

In that case, choose Sign into a different account, and then choose to Create a new account.

2. Follow the online instructions.

Part of the sign-up procedure involves receiving a phone call and entering a PIN using the phone keypad.

## Summarizing the changes:

1. Change the email address in AISPL account to a different one. This will also update your email address in amazon.com retail account as both are associated.
2. Now you can create a new AWS account using your previous email id and country of your choice.
3. Close your AISPL account as it is not required anymore.
4. Change your amazon.com retail account email address to the one you used for creating the AWS account.

Voila! You have now successfully created your new AWS account with your original AISPL email address.

Answer (score 0):

If you sign up for a new account and choose India for your contact address, your user agreement will be with Amazon Internet Services Pvt. Ltd (AISPL), a local AWS seller in India. AISPL will manage your billing, and your invoice total will be listed in rupees instead of dollars. Note that after you create an account with AISPL, you can't change the country in your contact information.

If you have an existing account with an India address, your account is either with AWS or AISPL, depending on when you opened the account. To learn whether your account is with AWS or AISPL, see the procedure [Determining Which Company Your Account is With](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/manage-account-payment-aispl.html#determine-seller). If you are an existing AWS customer, you can continue to use your AWS account. You also can choose to have both an AWS account and an AISPL account, though they can't be consolidated into the same payment family. For information about managing an AWS account, see [Managing an AWS Account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/manage-account-payment.html). (Currently, you can't migrate an existing account from AWS to AISPL.)

If your account is with AISPL, follow the procedures in this chapter to manage your account. This chapter explains how to sign up for an AISPL account, edit information about your AISPL account, and add or edit your Permanent Account Number (PAN).

You can google search for more Information. There are many docs available online. Check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/manage-account-payment-aispl.html) one too.